# Computing a Cartesian Product Ordered Pairs of Strings Using MatLab

Tags: matlab, cartesian-product

I'm trying to compute a 2 dimensional Cartesian Product ordered pairs of strings with a '/' as a delimiter between each possible pair of strings.

So far I have tried this:

```
A = char('hot / ', 'cold / ')
C = cellstr(A)
B = char('wet', 'dry')
D = cellstr(B)
ans = allcomb(C,D,'matlab')
```

What seems to be happening is the allcomb function is ordering all possible pairs of characters.

It would also be great if I could plot these pairs as a scatter plot, but then I imagine that each string would have to represent a number.  Or would it be easier to start with numbers that relate to strings if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: The expression `'wet'-0` will return an array of the ASCII codes in the string `wet`. That might help you.

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try and sadly it didn't work.  I get the error `Undefined function 'full' for input arguments of type 'cell'`